# Issue with global in PHP5 environment

Tags: php, global

I have a project from PHP4 which I am moving to PHP5 environment. It was developed by other developer long time back. In this developer has created a simple database connection using a DB class,

```
    $conn = new db(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE);
```

After that a function is created and in this function connection variable was declared as global

```
    function on_session_write($key, $val) 
    { 
        global $conn;

        error_log("$key = $value"); 

        $val = addslashes($val); 

        $query = "INSERT INTO tblSessions VALUES('$key','$val',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_add(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)),now())"; 
        $result = $conn->db_query($query);
        $error = $conn->db_get_error_msg();                 
    }
```

I get error as ***Fatal error: Call to a member function db_query() on a non-object...***

Why variable scope is limited and it is not available inside the function? What we can do so that it will be available inside the function...

Is it related to some PHP5 setting?

**We have consider following solution,**

1) If we decided to pass connection variable to function then we need to make updates at lot of places because it has been used at many places.

2) Using $GLOBALS also does not make any difference. Connection variable gets added in $GLOBALS but when we do var_dump inside the function it is empty. Outside the function it shows connection variable in $GLOBALS

Comment: It seems the variable is available, it's just not an object. Are you sure the DB connection doesn't just fail ?

Comment: When I do var_dump in php4 environment both inside and outside the function object is available

Comment: And what do you get in PHP5, for instance if you do `isset($conn)`

Comment: When I do var_dump() it prints NULL

Comment: Unless you're getting an `Undefined variable` error, it's defined and the `global` is working, the variable just has a `NULL` value

Comment: Nice example of why globals are _evil_. If your `on_session_write` function requires a DB connection, that connection should be passed as an argument by the caller. don't keep mucking about in the global namespace. PHP5's OOP support is a lot better than PHP4 (PS: make sure to remove those PHP4 style `&$conn` bits: call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated for a couple of years, too)